# When in account creation should I get auth session and ID?

Tags: 7, services, users

I am using the Services module version 7.x-3.2.

Posting a new user object to user/register.json, I get a response with status equal to 200, and an object with only uid and uri. If I then post username+password to login, I get a response with status equal to 406, and an "Already logged in" message. Then, if I post a new node object to node/, I get the message that I need authentication.

When, in the account creation process, am I supposed to get my session name, and ID so I can make authenticated requests?

Do I have to logout after creating the new account and log back in? This strange sequence is working, but logging out seems like it should be unnecessary.